# different colors for tags in aptana studio

Tags: xml, syntax-highlighting, aptana

I was doing XML in aptana studio.

Is it possible to show different colored tags for parent node, child node. Suppose I want to show **root node** with **red color** and child nodes with other colors. and for the text, it shows with other color. Similarly  the attributes be of different colors. It will help me with quick visual navigation.

How can I do this??

Answer (score 0):

(For Aptana Studio 3.x) Some of the colors can be controlled through the *Themes* preference page. Instructions for the scopes that can be colored is found at the wiki - http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Current+Theme+Scopes

Note that coloring parent-nodes and child-nodes, as you asked for, is not available in the current Studio version. You can also try the 'Outline View' for a quick navigation.

Cheers.